# Tabbing out of field causes "undefined" if left blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an amount field which calls a Javascript/JQuery function so if i am in the field and i press tab without entering am amount, i get `Undefined` displayed in my field.

I tried the below to remove it but it doesn't work and i have no idea of anything else i can do

```
$( "#ApproximateValue_TextBox" ).keydown(function(){
    alert("ApproximateValue_TextBox");
    document.getElementById("ApproximateValue_TextBox").value = "";
});

$( "#UncryAmount_TextBox" ).keydown(function(){
    alert("UncryAmount_TextBox");
    document.getElementById("UncryAmount_TextBox").value = "No";
});
```

```html
<tr id="OrigoUncryAmountField">
     <td><label id="AmountUnCryLabel" for="">Approximate amount</label></td>
     <td style="padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">£</td>
     <td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
          <input name="UncryAmount_TextBox" id="UncryAmount_TextBox" onkeyup="SubButtonToDisplay();" onblur="FormatCurrency(this)" type="any" value="UncryAmount_TextBox">
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: FormatCurrency might be doing this issue, would you please put code of this function

Comment: Second you should not set value of textfield as 'UncryAmount_TextBox'

Comment: you need to show us the `FormatCurrency(this)` as that is what is causing it - probably trying to do a number format on your blank field or "No" which will produce undefined or NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are binding event using jquery then why you not select element using jquery and take other advantages of jquery?

```js
$( "#ApproximateValue_TextBox" ).keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val("");
});

$( "#UncryAmount_TextBox" ).keydown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val("No");
});

function FormatCurrency(obj)
{
  // your some code here
}
function SubButtonToDisplay(obj)
{
// your some code here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="OrigoUncryAmountField">
     <td><label id="AmountUnCryLabel" for="">Approximate amount</label></td>
     <td style="padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">£</td>
     <td style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
          <input name="UncryAmount_TextBox" id="UncryAmount_TextBox" onkeyup="SubButtonToDisplay();" onblur="FormatCurrency(this)" type="any" value="UncryAmount_TextBox">
     </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```